# Laravel flash message and redirection not working properly

Tags: laravel, session, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm using laravel `5.8` and `"laracasts/flash": "^3.0"`

Within my application all redirections and flash messages are working well except for this very specific piece of code.

```
/* Controller */

public function show( Test $test) {
    $test->checkPermission();
    ...
}

/* Model */

public function checkPermission()
{
    flash()->warning('You can not have access to this.');
    return redirect( route('home' ) )->send();                    //Notice the send()
}
```

If i'm using this code with the `->send()`(that I never used before) I'm well redirected to the homepage but without flash message.

If I remove the `->send()`, I have got the flash message but I'm not redirected.

I also tried to remove the `flash()` and using `redirect()->with()`. Then the session is containing the message **and** I'm redirected. But I want to use `flash()` or atleast undertand why it's not working for this specific use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller should return the redirect, not the check permission. Try to return what check permission is returning in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the web middleware on your routes. or ensure the web middleware group contains the StartSession middleware.

via https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/auth-session-killed-after-redirect-laravel-52/replies/124991